# Breeze batch request with ODataConventionModelBuilder

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I try to implement Breeze together with a WebAPI OData WebService.

On the server side I use `ODataConventionModelBuilder` and `DefaultODataBatchHandler`:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<MyModelType>("MyModelTypes");
builder.Namespace = typeof(MyModelType).Namespace;

config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: "api",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

On the client side I use `webApiOData`:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
```

Service name is `/api`, and I use server side metadata:

```
var dataService = 
    new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: '/api', 
        hasServerMetadata: true  
    });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService
    });
```

If I try now to call `entityManager.saveChanges()` it correctly calls `/api/$batch`. But the changeset itself tries a POST to `/api/MyModelTypes`:

```
--batch_389a-6d15-37bd
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_a807-ab31-a36a

--changeset_a807-ab31-a36a
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST api/MyModelTypes HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"Id":-1,"Text":"Foo"}
--changeset_a807-ab31-a36a--

--batch_389a-6d15-37bd--
```

This results for the changeset in a call to `http://myhost/api/api/MyModelTypes` instead of `http://myhost/api/MyModelTypes`:

```
--batchresponse_4d3988b4-10e6-4df4-bae3-a1fa034a065c
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_b1df8cf5-8450-43f7-9eda-    5dc6bfdb7554

--changesetresponse_b1df8cf5-8450-43f7-9eda-5dc6bfdb7554
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-ID: 1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://myhost/api/api/MyModelTypes'."}
--changesetresponse_b1df8cf5-8450-43f7-9eda-5dc6bfdb7554--
--batchresponse_4d3988b4-10e6-4df4-bae3-a1fa034a065c--
```

What do I need to change to create Breeze the correct links in a batch request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this error was introduced sometimes between version 5.2.2 and 5.3.1 in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData and BreezeJS is not adopted yet accordingly:

[Can't save the data to OData controller after updating to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554218/odata-issue-after-updating-to-microsoft-aspnet-webapi-odata-5-3-x)

I've added an issue for BreezeJS: 
https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/42

Comment: And I add a comment to Pascal's post there explaining what I suggest that you do for now. Thanks, Pascal, for figuring this out.